# Writing R random forest results to a file

Tags: r, random-forest, cat

I am writing a R script to run Random Forest classification multiple times for my dataset. I wish to use average of at least 10 runs to get more robust results. So I have this function with for loop that is running Random Forest classifier as many times I wish (n = iterations).

```
iterateRandomForest <- function (samples,iterations,output_text,outname,pVSURF,b) {
   for (i in (1: iterations)) {

     cat("\n Loop starts", "\n", file=output_text,append=TRUE)    
     time <- toString(Sys.time())
     cat(time,"\n", file=output_text,append=TRUE)
     cat("Iteration number ",i," for variable set: ", outname, "\n", sep="",file=output_text,append=TRUE)

     load(pVSURF)
     sel.vars <- x$varselect.pred + 1
     colnames(samples[,sel.vars])

     ptm <- proc.time()                                                                # Start timer to calculate processing length
     (rf.final_ntree501 = randomForest(samples[,"species_na"], x=samples[,sel.vars], 
                       ntree=b, importance=TRUE, norm.votes=TRUE, proximity=TRUE) ) # Run randomForest

     ### PROBLEM HERE
     cat(rf.final_ntree501,file=output_text,append=TRUE)
     ### PROBLEM ENDS

     cat("Processing time: ",proc.time() - ptm, "\n", file=output_text,append=TRUE)      # Stop timer
     cat("Loop ends\n",  file=output_text,append=TRUE) 
  }
}
```

Usually you can just write the name of the created Random Forest object (rf.final_ntree501) to print the results as following:

```
Call:
  randomForest(x = samples[, sel.vars], y = samples[, "species_na"],      ntree = b, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE, norm.votes = TRUE) 
           Type of random forest: classification
                 Number of trees: 501
No. of variables tried at each split: 4

    OOB estimate of  error rate: 45.43%
Confusion matrix:
                 Acacia mearnsii Cupressus lusitanica Eucalyptus sp. Euphorbia sp. Ficus sp. Grevillea robusta Maesa lanceolata other Persea americana class.error
Acacia mearnsii                   34                    1              3             0         0                 7                0    28                0   0.5342466
Cupressus lusitanica               4                    3              8             0         0                13                0    16                0   0.9318182
Eucalyptus sp.                     5                    0             35             0         0                15                0     8                0   0.4444444
Euphorbia sp.                      0                    0              1            16         0                 2                0    15                0   0.5294118
Ficus sp.                          0                    0              0             1         1                 5                0    17                0   0.9583333
Grevillea robusta                  5                    2              3             0         1                91                0    29                1   0.3106061
Maesa lanceolata                   4                    0              0             0         0                 2                0    14                0   1.0000000
other                             16                    0              3             4         1                27                1   189                1   0.2190083
Persea americana                   5                    1              0             0         0                 6                0    33                1   0.9782609
```

> 

So I wish write this information to a file inside the loop (see. PROBLEM HERE part). I know that I cannot write RF object directly as it is a list. If I try to save the confusion matrix separately with rf.final_ntree501$confusion with cat. It will save the information but it will mess up the formulation of the matrix and put all information on one line excluding the class names.

Does anyone have good ideas how to handle this properly?

Cheers,
Rami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `capture.output()` instead of `cat()` to write the result into a file the way it is displayed in the console.

```
# generate random data
samples <- matrix(runif(675), ncol = 9)
resp <- as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:9], 75, replace = TRUE))

# random forest
rf <- randomForest(x = samples, y = resp, ntree = 501, 
    importance = TRUE, norm.votes = TRUE, proximity = TRUE)

# save desired information into a file
capture.output(rf, file = output_text, append = TRUE)
```

Saving the confusion matrix separately, you can use `write.table()`. The result will be formatted to a machine readable way with a chosen separator (tab in the example).

```
write.table(rf$confusion, file = "filename.txt", sep = "\t")
```